# Why did Samson hide from his parents the two incidents in Judges 14?

Tags: judges

Judges 14:6 (KJV)

> 6 And the spirit of the LORD came mightily upon him, and he rent him as he would have rent a kid, and he had nothing in his hand:  ***but he told not his father or his mother what he had done***.

Judges 14:8

> 8 And after a time he returned to take her, and he turned aside to see the carcase of the lion:  and, behold, there was a swarm of bees and honey in the carcase of the lion.   9 And he took thereof in his hands, and went on eating, and came to his father and mother, and he gave them, and they did eat:  ***but he told not them*** that he had taken the honey out of the carcase of the lion.

Later Samson uses the incidents to pose a riddle to the philistines.

Could this be the reason why Samson did not divulge the two incidents to his parents?

Comment: *Could this be the reason why Samson did not divulge the two incidents to his parents ?* - Not unless he had the power to foresee the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason could be out of humility: Samson didn't want to brag about his great strength to his parents. A comparable case could be when Samuel anointed Saul as king, but Saul didn't tell his uncle about it.

> Saul’s uncle said, “Tell me what Samuel said to you.”
>
> Saul replied, “He assured us that the donkeys had been found.” **But he did not tell his uncle what Samuel had said about the kingship.** (I Samuel 10:15-16, NIV)

In addition to this, from a literary point of view, the fact that Samson didn't tell his parents about this story is important to understand what he says to his wife later when she begs to know the answer to his riddle:

> So Samson’s wife wept before him, saying, “You hate me; you do not really love me. You have asked a riddle of my people, but you have not explained it to me.” He said to her, “Look, **I have not told my father or my mother**. Why should I tell you?” (Judges 14:16, NRSV)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in Judges 14:4 and in Judges 15:11.

> [Samson's] father and his mother knew not that it was of the Lord that he sought an occasion against the Philistines - *for at that time the Philistines had dominion over Israel.* Judges 14:4 [KJV].
>
> Knowest thou not that the Philistines are rulers over us ? What is this that thou hast done unto us ? Judges 15:11 [KJV].

Samson, alone, was resisting the occupying force. All that he did, he did alone, as moved of the Spirit of the Lord. "And the Spirit of the Lord came mightily upon him and he rent him [...]" Judges 14:6.

Samson's activity was clandestine for Israel was quietly accepting the dominion of the occupying force. At times, Israel was warned that they would be judged and warned not to resist, as happened, for example, in the days of Jeremiah.

But not so in Judges. Joshua had led them into the land and had apportioned the whole of Canaan for Israel to dwell in, safely and securely. It was Israel's fault that they had not striven enough to drive out every enemy. (And thereby hangs a lesson for every one who would follow a spiritual path.)

Joshua 23: 10 to 13 demonstrates what was set before Israel at that time. "One man of you shall chase a thousand" ... "If you do in any wise go back - they shall be snares and traps to you ..."

So Samson kept things close to his chest and told not even his parents of his secrets. But even such a warrior as Samson was tempted by a woman. And it was the very woman by whom he was actively seeking an occasion to rub up against the Philistines and erode their position of power, Judges 14:4.

Even she by whom he was inveigling himself among the Philistines became the source of his (temporary) downfall.

And what a lesson that is to every one who would walk a spiritual path. "Keep the doors of thy mouth from her that lieth in thy bosom" says Micah in 7:5.

Trust only in the Lord, especially in times when all around acquiesce to nature and the flesh in spiritual things.

As is done this very day.